# jqGrid get row data while row in edit mode

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have jqGrid 4.7.0. Does jqGrid have a function or method to get data of a row that has not been saved?

My table is a part of a larger form. I may add a row to it, then whith out saving the row I can press save. Currently the table is reloaded after every save, so that if I have a unsaved row the data is lost. I need it to retain the data. My idea was, before reload get the data into a variable and in loadComplete put the data back to table. But the problem I get is that getRowData gives me just the HTML code for the row but not the data in it. How can I get the values in the cells?

EDIT:

Ok i think i have found the place of problem but i dont know how to fix it. Seems like both on success and error the grid is reloaded. How can i stop it from reloading when save fails?

```
var saveParameters = {
            "successfunc" : success,
            "url" : null,
            "extraparam" : {},
            "aftersavefunc" : null,
            "errorfunc": null,
            "afterrestorefunc" : null,
            "restoreAfterError" : true,
            "mtype" : "POST"
        };

        jQuery(grid).jqGrid('saveRow', patsientId, saveParameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

So far only way to get row data in subscribed function is as follows but not efficient...

$("#jqGrid").bind("jqGridInlineAfterSaveRow", function (e, rowid, orgClickEvent) {

```
var data = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
$.each(data, function(index, item){
  if(item._id_ === rowid){
    console.log(item);
  }
});
```

});

Comment: Ok, so getting row data in edit mode is difficult. But is then there a way to reload the grid so that the edit row and its data will remain the same ?